# Multiclass Warlock/Wizard: Can I use Int as spellcasting ability for Pact Magic slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing, warlock

I would really love to play wizard/warlock multiclass with low charisma (just 13 for mutliclass). The handbook says that I can use Pact Magic slots to cast wizard spells, but doesn't specify which ability I use for spellcasting.

> Pact Magic.
>   If you have both the Spellcasting class feature and the Pact Magic class feature from the warlock class, you can use the spell slots you gain from the Pact Magic feature to cast spells you know or have prepared from classes with the Spellcasting class feature, and [vice versa].

When I cast wizard spells using Pact Magic slots (or warlock spells using wizard's "Spellcasting" slots) do I use spellcasting ability of the slot, or do I get to choose?

Comment: This is a good question, as some others may be interested in the answer.  A possibly related question: [Do cantrips gained through Pact of the Tome use Charisma or their default stat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49453/do-cantrips-gained-through-pact-of-the-tome-use-charisma-or-their-default-stat)

Answer (score 33):

You use the ability associated with the class you learned the spell from.

For example, *charm person* is on both the warlock and the wizard spell list. If you learned it when you took a level in warlock, then it counts as a warlock spell and uses your Charisma modifier. If you learned it when you took a level in wizard (or by finding a scroll or spellbook and copying it into your own book), you cast it using your Intelligence modifier because it counts as a wizard spell.

> If you have both the Spellcasting class feature and the Pact Magic class feature,...[and] you can use the spell slots you gain from the Spellcasting class feature to cast warlock spells you know. (*PHB*, 164)

> Charisma is your spellcasting ability for your warlock spells, so you use your Charisma whenever a spell refers to your spellcasting ability. In addition, you use your Charisma modifier when setting the saving throw DC for a warlock spell you cast and when making an attack roll with one. (*PHB*, 107)

In other words, it is not the spell slot that restricts what ability score you use, it is the spell itself (or more importantly, how you learned it).

Comment: Note that you can learn a spell multiple times to have access to casting it multiple ways.  You probably don't want to spend warlock spells known on wizard spells you can already cast, but if you run into a scroll of a spell you know as a warlock there's not really much reason not to learn it as a wizard.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer It's not that you can't; it's that there's no point. The other part of the quote that I cut off because it wasn't relevant to the original question was that you can cast warlock spells from non-warlock spell slots. You can already cast spells multiple ways simply through the mechanics of multiclassing in 5e; thus, the only reason you would pick up a spell you already had through another class was that you wanted to use a different ability score to cast it.

Comment: @chif-ii Sure, but I never said there was much reason to do so in general.  I merely pointed out that you could, and that doing so as a Warlock was a bad idea while doing so as a wizard lacked any serious negative consequences.

Answer (score -4):

> **Pact Magic**. If you have both the Spellcasting class feature and the Pact Magic class feature from the warlock class, you can use the spell slots you gain from the Pact Magic feature to cast spells you know or have prepared from classes with the Spellcasting class feature you can use the spell slots you gain from the Spellcasting class feature to cast warlock spells you know.

This means you can cast both, warlock spells with wizard spell slots, and wizard spells with warlock spell slots, and you must use the Spellcasting ability of the chosen spell slot (Cha for warlock and Int for wizard).

Comment: You use the spellcasting ability of which class you obtained the spell from, not the spellcasting ability of which spell slot you used. (The latter wouldn't work for, say, a cleric/wizard multiclass since there's no spell slot 'source' for multiclassed Spellcasters)